# AWK: Print contents of random file in reverse order

Tags: awk

Say we have a file where each line has a different word count.
Like this:

```
Douglas Texn 98 64 44
54 88 27 37
Violet Denesik Texn 40 89 70
Blanche Hoeger
Johnathon Schultz Texn 51 41 24 96
```

I want to print it in reverse order. Like this

```
96 24 41 51 Texn Schultz Johnathon
...
44 64 98 Texn Douglas
```

My idea is to reverse the order of the lines first, and then the columns, but I can't implement the second part.

Code implementing the first part

```
{a[NR]=$0} END {for(i=NR;i>0;i--)print a[i]}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tac` [man tac](http://ss64.com/bash/tac.html), "concatenate and write files in reverse", previous to `awk`

```
tac file | awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF/2; ++i){ temp=$i; $i=$(NF-i+1); $(NF-i+1)=temp }}1'
```

you get,

```
96 24 41 51 Texn Schultz Johnathon
Hoeger Blanche
70 89 40 Texn Denesik Violet
37 27 88 54
44 64 98 Texn Douglas
```

**explanation**

`temp=$i; $i=$(NF-i+1); $(NF-i+1)=temp` is swap algorithm,

```
temp := x
x := y
y := temp
```

**EDIT: Only `awk` solution**

```
awk '{
    for(i=1; i<=NF/2; ++i){ temp=$i; $i=$(NF-i+1); $(NF-i+1)=temp }
    a[c++]=$0
}END{--c; for(;c>=0;c--){print a[c]}}' file
```

you get,

```
96 24 41 51 Texn Schultz Johnathon
Hoeger Blanche
70 89 40 Texn Denesik Violet
37 27 88 54
44 64 98 Texn Douglas
```

Comment: Would like to use it but I want to use only awk for practice. I just can't get my head around this one :/

Comment: @Dinos_12345 I add awk solution

Comment: That's simple and brilliant! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to reverse the sequence of the words:

```
awk '{x=split($0,a); for(i=x;i!=0;i--){y=y?y OFS a[i]:a[i];}print y;y=""}' file
```

Comment: Can you explain what this part does? `{y=y?y OFS a[i]:a[i];}print y;y=""` Thank you :)

Comment: If y is empty, assign a[i] to y, else concatnate y and a[i] and assign it back to y.

Comment: I see that you're checking if `y=y` which doesn't make sense because it's always true.

Comment: @Dinos_12345: No, y=y make sense. So let's say very first value of a[I] then it should go to wild character :'s condition which is to simple keep it a[I]'s value. And if you see ?'s value which appends the value of current a[I] to y's previous value so if you do not check y=y it will give a NULL value in front of y variable.

Comment: @Dinos_12345 it's a ternary expression (google that phrase), much more easily understandable when parenthesized: `y=(y?y OFS a[i]:a[i])` and simplified: `y=(y?y OFS:"") a[i]`. Note that it will fail if/when y has the value zero though - the test should be `y!=""` not just `y`. I'd actually write it as `y=(y==""?"":y OFS) a[i]` to avoid the negative condition.

Comment: I know what it is! As a matter of fact I use it all the time in Ruby, but without `()` it's really hard to make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Dinos_123455, could you please try following and let me know if this helps. if your o.s supports tac command then following may help you in same.

```
tac file1 | awk '{for(i=NF;i>0;i--){printf("%s ",$i)};print X}'
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:** As per your request, only awk solution following may help you in same too.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[++i]=$0;next} {for(k=i;k>0;k--){num=split(A[k], array," ");for(q=num;q>0;q--){printf("%s ",array[q])};if(A[k]){print X};delete A[k]}}' file1 file1
```

Comment: Would like to use it but I want to use only awk for practice.

Comment: @Dinos_12345, as per your request added a solution with only awk, kindly let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @Dinos_12345, it completely depends on people their perspective, I LIKED the solution provided by Jose but as per your request I tried to post in single awk for helping.

Comment: Tried it and it works, so you get an upvote :) Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ awk '{a[NR][1]; split($0,a[NR])} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc"; for (r in a) for (c in a[r]) printf "%s%s", a[r][c], (c>1?OFS:ORS)}' file
96 24 41 51 Texn Schultz Johnathon
Hoeger Blanche
70 89 40 Texn Denesik Violet
37 27 88 54
44 64 98 Texn Douglas
```

With other awks:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END{for (r=NR;r>0;r--) { nc=split(a[r],b); for (c=nc;c>0;c--) printf "%s%s", b[c], (c>1?OFS:ORS) } }' file
96 24 41 51 Texn Schultz Johnathon
Hoeger Blanche
70 89 40 Texn Denesik Violet
37 27 88 54
44 64 98 Texn Douglas
```

Answer (score 1):

An all awk version:

```
$ awk '{ for(i=NF;i>=1;i--)                  # iterate fields backwards
             a[NR]=a[NR] sprintf ($i OFS) }  # append to array indexed on NR
   END { for(i=NR;i>=1;i--)                  # reverse NR order
             print a[i] }' file              # output
96 24 41 51 Texn Schultz Johnathon 
Hoeger Blanche 
70 89 40 Texn Denesik Violet 
37 27 88 54 
44 64 98 Texn Douglas
```